# Does Android OS has one `ContentResolver` object that is shared by all the apps or does each app has their own instance of `ContentResolver`?

Tags: java, android, android-contentprovider, android-contentresolver

I am undergoing an Android Course on Udacity and came across the question in the title by a fellow learner.

[Youtube link to lesson](https://youtu.be/3MABuLQncrQ?t=32)

Quoting from the video:

```
ContentResolver resolver = getContentResolver();
Cursor cursor = resolver.query(DroidTermsExampleContract.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
```

> This code accesses the correct content provider and grabs some data
>   from it. We've got some new concepts of vocabulary here, so I'm going
>   to break it down. The first new concept is the ContentResolver. So our
>   original diagram is fairly simplistic. Let's look at this drawing that
>   we saw before.

[image: Simple]

> The more accurate version of this drawing is this.

[image: More Accurate]

> And
>   this drawing involves a content resolver. So what's the purpose of
>   having this class sit between your app and direct access to the
>   content provider?
>
> If you think about it, there are multiple content
>   providers on your phone, and you add more content providers when you
>   download apps that store local data, which use content providers.
>   Besides the DroidTermsExample content provider, you have a content
>   provider for contacts, your device has one for user files of the
>   device, one that keeps track of user alarms, the calendar provider,
>   and some others.
>
> Also, your app is not the only app running on the
>   device. There are other apps that might also be using content
>   providers in parallel. Managing what content providers are talking to
>   what apps, and keeping all the data in sync, could turn into a huge
>   traffic jam. That's where the content resolver comes in.
>
> **The content resolver acts as an intermediary between each app and the
>   content provider, or providers, it wants to access. It handles
>   inter-process communication and keeps everything in sync and running
>   smoothly.** Even if you have five processes accessing two content
>   providers.
>
> So wherever you want to use a Content Provider, you'll need
>   to do it through a ContentResolver. Okay, so now you know what this
>   first line is doing,

```
ContentResolver resolver = getContentResolver();
```

> **getting us a reference to the system's Content
>   Resolver.** This is the next step for accessing the Content Provider.

The explanation in the video(especially the bold marked lines above) clearly makes me think that there is one `ContentResolver` for an Android OS.

And its job is to make the life easier for all such apps that want to talk to the content provider of one or many apps.

---

However, fellow learners seem to have the opposite understanding. Some arguments given are:

From [androiddesignpatterns](https://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/06/content-resolvers-and-content-providers.html):

> The Content Resolver is the single, global instance in your
>   application that provides access to your (and other applications’)
>   content providers.

And from [Android docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics.html):

> When you want to access data in a content provider, you use the
>   ContentResolver object in your application's Context to communicate
>   with the provider as a client.

The claim:

> Since it is mentioned **ContentResolver object in your application's
>   Context**, hence each Application has it's own Content Resolver

I still have a simple fair understanding that the OS provides a single `ContentResolver` and this resolver is then brought to the given applications's context to make use of it. Isn't it possible?

This is my very first Android course and I am an absolute beginner here. Can someone please clarify if I am having a wrong understanding of the concept?

Comment: Yes , you are correct !!

Answer (score 3):

There is only **one** single instance of the [**`ContentResolver`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html) class in any given application.

Looking at the source of the actual [`ContextImpl`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/nougat-mr1.2-release/core/java/android/app/ContextImpl.java) class (class that actually implements the `Context` interface)  in Android's source, you will find an inner static [`ApplicationContentResolver`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/nougat-mr1.2-release/core/java/android/app/ContextImpl.java#2207) subclass of the abstract [`ContentResolver`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/nougat-mr1.2-release/core/java/android/content/ContentResolver.java) class that manages all the communication between an application and the system server. An instance of `ApplicationContentResolver` is  created inside the constructor of `ContextImpl` and is unique for that context (or application).

The `ApplicationContentResolver` delegates it's calls to the [`ActivityThread`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/nougat-mr1.2-release/core/java/android/app/ActivityThread.java) class which is responsible to manage the *main thread* of the application and provide an IPC-communication (via binder) to the system server. In the `ActivityThread` class you will find calls like [`ActivityThread#acquireProvider()`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/nougat-mr1.2-release/core/java/android/app/ActivityThread.java#5461) that either re-uses an existing provider (and increment it's reference count) or *asks* the [`ActivityManagerNative`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/nougat-mr1.2-release/core/java/android/app/ActivityManagerNative.java) to get a new instance of the provider via *system server*. This is an important step as at this point the system server would check if the calling application has the required permission or not.

Once the system server decides that the calling application has sufficient permissions to use the `ContentProvider`, it then either *creates* a `ContentProvider` or *re-uses* on if it exists and returns a reference to that to the calling application.

From the documentation on `ContentProvider`,

> **Data access methods** may be called from *many threads* at once, and must be *thread-safe*. Other methods (such as onCreate()) are only called from the *application main thread*, and must avoid performing lengthy operations.

This implies that a single `ContentProvider` instance is shared between multiple application and it's lifecycle is managed by system (just like for other components).

So to conclude form this, there is **one** single `ContentResolver` instance per application and also **one** single `ContentProvider` instance (for a given authority) for the whole system.

Comment: **So to conclude form this, there is one single ContentResolver instance per application...**

So you mean to say in my hypothetical Android device which has 5 _applications_ on it(assuming all need ContentResolver), there are 5 `ContentResolver` instance on my device?

Comment: Yes indeed! As each application has it's own `Context` and each context has it's own resolver (see [this](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/nougat-mr1.2-release/core/java/android/app/ContextImpl.java#2096)) this means that each application has a single content resolver associated with it

Comment: P.S. I am also taking the same course :) can you share the link to the post here too ? and also your handle?

Comment: @VikasPrasad You should up accept this answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: @riyaz-ali my handle is [at]Vikas Prasad

Comment: @VikasPrasad sure! can you tell me which part is still confusing to you?

Comment: Beware if you are calling `getContentResolver()` and `getBaseContext().getContentResolver()` inside an `Activity`. Each `Activity` instance has it's own `ContentResolver`. You can check it by yourself by printing out its hashcode via `Logcat`. So be careful if you're holding `ContentResolver` from `Activity` since you might have a memory leak.